# Parsing Unstructured Text file in SSIS and read the each line to get the required data

Tags: sql, ssis

I am working on SSIS and I am having the complex unstructured TEXT File, I have to parse the text file through creating SSIS Packages and get the required column's data in the DataBase.What is the best way to parse the Textfile and how can I write the Script to read each line in that Text file. I was also confused whether I can read the each line of the TEXT file without writing script?

Required columns from the Text file data is DEVICEID, DATAVALUE and DATAUNITS :

Here is the TEXT File:

```
    12/02/2015 09:47:44:745 SecureHARTPort version: 1.1.12.0.

    12/02/2015 09:47:44:745 Connecting and initialing Session to 
    67.40.65.181 Port:5094 Tcp
    12/02/2015 09:47:44:745 Tx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 0, MsgId: 0 
    Status: 0x00
   TranId: 1, Data ByteCount: 5
   Data: 01 00 09 27 C0 

    12/02/2015 09:47:44:761 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 0 
   Status: 0x00
  TranId: 1, Data ByteCount: 5
  Data: 01 00 09 27 C0 
  12/02/2015 09:47:44:855 Tx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 0, MsgId: 3 
  Status: 0x00
 TranId: 2, Data ByteCount: 5
 Data: 02 80 00 00 82 

 12/02/2015 09:47:44:855 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 3 
 Status: 0x00
 TranId: 2, Data ByteCount: 29
 Data: 06 80 00 18 00 50 FE 26 4E 05 07 05 02 0E 0C 0B 6A 64 05 04 00 01 50 
 00 26 00 26 84 8E 

 Rx Cmd=0, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
 Expansion Code=254
 Expanded Device Type=9806
 # Request Preambles=5
 Universal Comand Revision Level=7
 Transmitter HART Revision Level=5
 Software Revision=2
 Hardware Revision Level / Physical Signaling Code=14
 Flags=0C
 Device ID=748132
 Minimum # Response Preambles=5
 Max # of device variables=4
 Configuration Change Counter=1
 Extended Field Device Status=50
 Manufacturer's ID=38
 Private Label Distributor=38
 Device Profile=132

 12/02/2015 09:47:44:855 Tx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 0, MsgId: 3 
 Status: 0x00
 TranId: 3, Data ByteCount: 9
  Data: 82 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 14 00 7B 

  12/02/2015 09:47:44:870 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 3 
  Status: 0x00
  TranId: 3, Data ByteCount: 43
  Data: 86 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 14 22 00 50 77 69 68 61 72 74 67 77 00 00 00 00 00 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 

 Rx Cmd=20, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
 Long Tag=wihartgw

  12/02/2015 09:47:44:870 Tx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 0, MsgId: 3 
 Status: 0x00
 TranId: 4, Data ByteCount: 9
 Data: 82 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 4A 00 25 

 12/02/2015 09:47:44:886 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 3 
 Status: 0x00
 TranId: 4, Data ByteCount: 19
  Data: 86 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 4A 0A 00 50 01 01 65 00 05 02 01 03 1B 

  Rx Cmd=74, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
 Max Num IO Cards=1
 Max Num Channels per IO Card=1
 Max Num Sub-Devices per Channel=101
  Num Devices Detected=5
  Max Num DR Supported=2
  Master Mode for Comm=1
   Retry Count for Sub-Device=3

   Rx Cmd=9, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
   Extended Device Status=0
   Slot0 Var Code=246
   Slot0 Var Classification=0
   Slot0 Var Units=251
   Slot0 Var Value=4
   Slot0 Var Status=C0
   Slot1 Var Code=116
  Slot1 Var Classification=209
  Slot1 Var Units=70
 Slot1 Var Value=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will help you, but with a T-SQL script like the following you can first read the text *line-by-line* and then use an appropriate filter:

```
DECLARE @YourText NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'    12/02/2015 09:47:44:745 SecureHARTPort version: 1.1.12.0.

    12/02/2015 09:47:44:745 Connecting and initialing Session to 
    67.40.65.181 Port:5094 Tcp
    12/02/2015 09:47:44:745 Tx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 0, MsgId: 0 
    Status: 0x00
   TranId: 1, Data ByteCount: 5
   Data: 01 00 09 27 C0 

    12/02/2015 09:47:44:761 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 0 
   Status: 0x00
  TranId: 1, Data ByteCount: 5
  Data: 01 00 09 27 C0 
  12/02/2015 09:47:44:855 Tx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 0, MsgId: 3 
  Status: 0x00
 TranId: 2, Data ByteCount: 5
 Data: 02 80 00 00 82 

 12/02/2015 09:47:44:855 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 3 
 Status: 0x00
 TranId: 2, Data ByteCount: 29
 Data: 06 80 00 18 00 50 FE 26 4E 05 07 05 02 0E 0C 0B 6A 64 05 04 00 01 50 
 00 26 00 26 84 8E 

 Rx Cmd=0, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
 Expansion Code=254
 Expanded Device Type=9806
 # Request Preambles=5
 Universal Comand Revision Level=7
 Transmitter HART Revision Level=5
 Software Revision=2
 Hardware Revision Level / Physical Signaling Code=14
 Flags=0C
 Device ID=748132
 Minimum # Response Preambles=5
 Max # of device variables=4
 Configuration Change Counter=1
 Extended Field Device Status=50
 Manufacturer''s ID=38
 Private Label Distributor=38
 Device Profile=132

 12/02/2015 09:47:44:855 Tx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 0, MsgId: 3 
 Status: 0x00
 TranId: 3, Data ByteCount: 9
  Data: 82 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 14 00 7B 

  12/02/2015 09:47:44:870 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 3 
  Status: 0x00
  TranId: 3, Data ByteCount: 43
  Data: 86 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 14 22 00 50 77 69 68 61 72 74 67 77 00 00 00 00 00 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 

 Rx Cmd=20, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
 Long Tag=wihartgw

  12/02/2015 09:47:44:870 Tx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 0, MsgId: 3 
 Status: 0x00
 TranId: 4, Data ByteCount: 9
 Data: 82 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 4A 00 25 

 12/02/2015 09:47:44:886 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 3 
 Status: 0x00
 TranId: 4, Data ByteCount: 19
  Data: 86 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 4A 0A 00 50 01 01 65 00 05 02 01 03 1B 

  Rx Cmd=74, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
 Max Num IO Cards=1
 Max Num Channels per IO Card=1
 Max Num Sub-Devices per Channel=101
  Num Devices Detected=5
  Max Num DR Supported=2
  Master Mode for Comm=1
   Retry Count for Sub-Device=3

   Rx Cmd=9, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
   Extended Device Status=0
   Slot0 Var Code=246
   Slot0 Var Classification=0
   Slot0 Var Units=251
   Slot0 Var Value=4
   Slot0 Var Status=C0
   Slot1 Var Code=116
  Slot1 Var Classification=209
  Slot1 Var Units=70
 Slot1 Var Value=0';
```

--The query will cut the lines at any combination of `CHAR(13) and/or CHAR(10)`:

```
 WITH LineByLine AS
 (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS LineNr
           ,LTRIM(RTRIM(x.value(N'(text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)'))) AS Line
    FROM
    (
    SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourText,NCHAR(10),NCHAR(13)),NCHAR(13)+NCHAR(13),NCHAR(13)),NCHAR(13),N'\nl') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),N'\nl',N'</x><x>')  + N'</x>'AS XML) AS Casted
    ) AS t
    CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes(N'/x[text()]') AS A(x)
 )
 SELECT LineNr,Line
 FROM LineByLine
 WHERE CHARINDEX('Device ID=',Line)>0
    OR CHARINDEX('Data:',Line)>0
    OR CHARINDEX('unit',Line)>0;
```

The result would be:

```
Nr  Line
7   Data: 01 00 09 27 C0
11  Data: 01 00 09 27 C0
15  Data: 02 80 00 00 82
19  Data: 06 80 00 18 00 50 FE 26 4E 05 07 05 02 0E 0C 0B 6A 64 05 04 00 01 50
30  Device ID=748132
41  Data: 82 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 14 00 7B
45  Data: 86 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 14 22 00 50 77 69 68 61 72 74 67 77 00 00 00 00 00
52  Data: 82 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 4A 00 25
56  Data: 86 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 4A 0A 00 50 01 01 65 00 05 02 01 03 1B
69  Slot0 Var Units=251
74  Slot1 Var Units=70
```

You did not state your expected output, neither are the stated column names within your text, so this is guessing... Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks, But I need the help how to write the script in the script component to read the each line, because I am not familiar with the hard code.

Comment: @akhil a synchronous script component has a method called InputBuffer0_ProcessInputRow which is called on each line. [Read more in this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-synchronous-transformation-with-the-script-component), but you have to write this script in c# or Vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use a script task to handle this.

The script task can use the File System Object to get a reference to the file and read it line by line, looking for strings like:

```
Device ID=xxx
Value=xxx
Units=xxx
```

And getting whatever the value of `xxx` is in each case, and inserting it to the database.